# Button Back in Browser with Frames (history forward don't work)

Tags: javascript, jsp, browser

I have jsp aplication.
I want, that button Back don't work.
history.forward - not suitable, that transitions occur in frame.
In Google chrome when I go in my jsp aplication create history transitions in frame, and button Back becomes active. I need disable button Back or when button back is pressed - nothing happened. Open new windows without toolbar - ot suitable.
history.forward - good work if simple internet page.
In jsp project with frames hi does not behave predictably.
I need, than it wark in google chrome and IE (maby can write individually to each his own)

How do it?

Comment: What is it you are asking? Please take another look at your question, the quality is really poor. Tried to edit it, but is does not make any sense to be honoust.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
<body onload="onLoad();" onpageshow="if (event.persisted) onLoad();">
```

because Firefox 1.5 uses in-memory caching for entire Web pages, including their JavaScript states, for a single browser session. Going backward and forward between visited pages requires no page loading and the JavaScript states are preserved.

[Click here for your reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_Firefox_1.5_caching)

Answer (score 1):

You can't disable the browser's back button. The best you can do is write your application so that using the back burron doesn't break anything.

Comment: You'll need to edit your question and describe exactly what is breaking in your application when you use the back button. Then someone may be able to give more specific help.

Comment: Like Gareth says, this is not possible. The `Back` button is a privilege of the user and should be that way. Explain what the intented behaviour is. Disabling the `Back` button is just wrong.